# Can I set a variable if a value exists in another table?

Tags: mysql

There are 3 tables and a `staff_id` is given.

```
staff(staff_id, gender)
contract(staff_id, contract_id)
full_time_contract(contract_id, start_date)
```

and I declared a variable "num" INT

How can I set `num = num + 1`

if the given staff is in `full_time_contract`?

Comment: Where will the `num` be stored? in the `staff` table?

Comment: @Raptor I'm not going to store `num` value! 
`
I just wanted to count how many contracts the given staff have :) 

I have `part_time_contract table`, `casual table` as well :)

Comment: then, use `COUNT()`

Comment: @Cid can I stored `COUNT()` value in a variable? so that I can add more numbers?    (Sorry mention doesn't work )

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially pp. 5 and 3.

Comment: Is the `contract_id` unique for FullTime contracts and Part Time contracts? i.e. the same `contract_id` will not be used for both tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count how many full-time contracts the staff have, you can use `COUNT()`:

```
SELECT staff_id, COUNT() AS cnt FROM contract c 
LEFT JOIN full_time_contact ft
ON c.contract_id=ft.contract_id
GROUP BY staff_id
```